# linked list errors

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I just test the function on one of the struct which is name but it won't reach them.
This is the full code so far:

update:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    string name;
    string address;
    int phoneNum;
    struct Node* next;
};

Node insertInOrder(Node p, string theName);
void push(struct Node*& head, string theName);


int main(){

    cout<<"\tEnter S or s to show the list contents \n"
        <<"\tEnter A or a to add a node to the list \n"
        <<"\tEnter D or d to delete a node from the list \n"
        <<"\tEnter Q or q to quiet the program \n"
    <<"Make your selection: "<<endl;

    struct Node* newNode = new Node;
    push(newNode, "yeah");

    cout<<newNode;

    return 0;

}

void push(struct Node*& head, string theName){
    struct Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->name = theName;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

Node insertInOrder(Node p, string theName){
    if(p == NULL || p.name >= theName){
        return new Node(p, theName);
    }
    else{
            p.next = insertInOrder(p.next, theName);
            return p;
        }
    }
```

I get an error that says: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Node’ for this code:

```
    void push(struct Node*& head, string theName){
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->name = theName;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}
```

I'm trying to translate this code into my code but I got an error:

```
 Node insertInOrder( int k, Node p ) {
   if( p == " " || p.item >= k ) 
      return new Node( k, p ); 
   else {
      p.next = insertInOrder( k, p.next ); 
      return p;
   }
}
```

This is how I translated it:

```
Node insertInOrder(Node p, string theName){
    if(p == " " || p.name >= theName){
        return new Node(p, theName);
    }
    else{
            p.next = insertInOrder(p.next, theName);
            return p;
        }
    }
```

here is the error for this code:

```
 if(p == " " || p.name >= theName){
        return new Node(p, theName);
```

Errors:

```
- comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]
- request for member ‘name’ in ‘p’, which is of pointer type ‘Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘-
 >’ ?)
- comparison between distinct pointer types ‘Node*’ and ‘const char*’ lacks a cast [-
 fpermissive]
```

p.next = insertInOrder(p.next, theName);
return p;

errors:

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: Node insertInOrder(Node, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>) '
- could not convert ‘p.Node::next’ from ‘Node*’ to ‘Node’
```

Answer (score 1):

Some points:

- forget `malloc` since you are working with C++ and use `new` and `delete`
- you don't need to specify that node is a struct again whenever you use it so `sizeof(Node)` is enough, but you won't directly use malloc
- your function `Node insertInOrder(Node p, string theName)` accepts a concrete Node and return a concrete `Node` but the field next inside your struct is a pointer to a `Node`, I guess you shoul be consistent in what you are using and since you are working with a linked list using pointers is more suitable
- you can't use a comparison operator directly between a value and a string literal (`p == " "`), you should check `name` field only

Comment: I updated my code. would you mind taking a look. for the (p= " "), I want to check if it is null.